# C++ "No matching constructor for initializing Employee"

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ and practicing using vector as an object. However, I got an error "No matching constructor for initializing Employee" when I tried running the following program.
Please tell me how I could modify my program!

Also, when I write
staff[0] = Employee{"Harry Potter" 55000};
does this mean that I am storing string and double data in one of 10 open boxes in vector object of type Employee?

I apologize for such a basic question.
Thank you so much in advance!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
    public:
        Employee(string, double);
        double get_salaries();
        string get_name();
        void set_salaries(double);
    private:
        string name;
        double salaries;
};
Employee::Employee(string n, double s)
{
    name = n;
    salaries = s;
}
double Employee::get_salaries()
{
    return salaries;
}
string Employee::get_name()
{
    return name;
}
void Employee::set_salaries(double s)
{
    salaries = s;
}

int main()
{
    // using vector as an object

    int i;
    vector<Employee> staff(10);                   
    staff[0] = Employee{"Harry Potter", 55000};

    if (staff[i].get_salaries() < 100000)
        cout << staff[i].get_salaries();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `staff[0] = Employee("Harry Potter", 55000);` should do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Employee` class does not have a default, parameterless, constructor.
When you create the `staff` vector, it will create 10 `Employee` objects, thus invoking the default constructor.

Comment: Thank you guys all for answering my question!
I chose this answer because he responded quickly to both of my questions :)!!

Answer (score 1):

To support this,

```
vector<Employee> staff(10);
```

you have to provide default constructor in your class.

Answer (score -1):

Your main method

```
int main()
{
    // using vector as an object

    int i;                           // [i] not initialized anywhere.      
    vector<Employee> staff(10);     // Incorrect way of declaring a vector                 
    staff[0] = Employee{"Harry Potter", 55000}; // Incorrect way of creating a instance of class

    if (staff[i].get_salaries() < 100000)
        cout << staff[i].get_salaries();


    return 0;
}
```

Change your main method like this

```
 int main()
{
     vector<Employee> staff;         
     staff.push_back(Employee("Harry Potter", 55000));

    if (staff[0].get_salaries() < 100000)
        cout << staff[0].get_salaries();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would no the `Employee emp(...` line be a `Most vexing parse` issue, or is it too early for me to think? :)

Comment: Initialising the Employee objects with `{}` instead of `()` as the OP does, should be more correct (`Uniform initialization` c++11), cause of the `Most vexing parse problem`.